# d3.js replace nodes with images

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here's the code I am running http://jsfiddle.net/a7as6/14/

I know that I can use this code to change node to image:

```
node.append("svg:image")
    .attr("class", "circle")
    .attr("xlink:href", "https://github.com/favicon.ico")
    .attr("x", "-8px")
    .attr("y", "-8px")
    .attr("width", "16px")
    .attr("height", "16px");
```

But when I use it and my nodes are still not images. Any idea why?

And I am wondering how to change each nodes with different images?

Thx.

Answer (score 2):

You've got the right idea for appending the images, but you need to operate on node.enter() as in:

```
   node.enter().append("image")
       .attr("class", function (d) {
           return "node " + d.id;
           })
       .attr("xlink:href", "https://github.com/favicon.ico")
       .attr("width", "16px")
       .attr("height", "16px");
```

You then need to get your tick function to place the images, as in:

```
function tick() {
   node.attr("x", function (d) {
       return d.x;
   })
       .attr("y", function (d) {
       return d.y;
   })
```

And here's the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EeurX/).  Not that you'll need to move the images around so they look right, you can use the dx and dy properties to bump them.